# How to Access Child of a node with a dynamic node name in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

im stuck with this issue.

I have this XML:

```
<Document>
  <Type>ABC</Type>
  <Header>
    <Date>15-01-2017</Date>
    <Time>11:00 AM</Time>
  </Header>
  <Body>
    <Name>Juan</Name>
    <Age>10</Age>
    <Address>
      <City>City</City>
      <Country>Country</Country>
      <Block>Block</Block>
    </Address>
  </Body>
</Document>
```

And i have this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name ="DocumentType" select ="//Document/Type" />

  <xsl:template match ="Document">
    <Root>
      <xsl:apply-templates select ="Header" />
      <xsl:element name="Data{$DocumentType}">
        <xsl:call-template name="Data">
          <xsl:with-param name="type" select ="$DocumentType" />
        </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:element>
    </Root>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name ="Data">
    <xsl:param name="type" />
    <Name>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Body/Name" />
    </Name>
    <Age>
      <xsl:value-of select ="Body/Age" />
    </Age>
    <xsl:element name="Address{$type}">
      <City>
        <xsl:value-of select ="City"/>
      </City>
      <Country>
        <xsl:value-of select ="Country"/>
      </Country>
      <Block>
        <xsl:value-of select ="Block"/>
      </Block>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match ="Header">
    <Header>
      <DateCreated>
        <xsl:value-of select ="Date"/>
      </DateCreated>
      <TimeCreated>
        <xsl:value-of select ="Time"/>
      </TimeCreated>
    </Header>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

my problem is I cannot access the values of the child node of the address in the XML, I am only seeing this:

```
<Root>
  <Header>
    <DateCreated>15-01-2017</DateCreated>
    <TimeCreated>11:00 AM</TimeCreated>
  </Header>
  <DataABC>
    <Name>Juan</Name>
    <Age>10</Age>
    <AddressABC>
      <City></City>
      <Country></Country>
      <Block></Block>
    </AddressABC>
  </DataABC>
</Root>
```

Can anyone help me to show me my mistake.

Thanks

Comment: I am puzzled why do you apply templates to `Header`, but choose to call a named template to handle `Body`. And of course the identity transform template tacked on at the end does not do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake has already been pointed out in Michael Kay's answer.

I wanted to suggest an alternative approach - one that requires a lot less work:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="DocumentType" select="/Document/Type" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/Document">
    <Root>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Header | Body"/>
    </Root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Body">
    <xsl:element name="Data{$DocumentType}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Date | Time">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}Created">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Address">
    <xsl:element name="Address{$DocumentType}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

Note that a global variable is accessible from any template and does not need to be sent down as a parameter.

Comment: is it possible to use a string like "Address{$DocumentType}" as a template name or match? because I might have a need for a tempate like that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45108406/need-to-replace-a-value-in-the-match-part-of-xslt#comment77188621_45108406 Not sure how this relates to your question above.

Answer (score 1):

Just as you use `Body/Name` to get the name, you can use `Body/Address/City` to get the city (because the context item is the `Document` element).

However, your code is a little bit monolithic. Doing an `xsl:apply-templates` on the Address element might be better, and then a template rule with `match="Address"`, wherein you can use `select="City"` to select the `City` relative to the `Address`.